# How can I Identify who calls a gwt service using eclipse debug?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, gwt, rpc

Im trying to identify which code from the client is calling a gwt rpc service but the stack on my debug view in eclipse doesnt show me the caller for the service.

Is there a way to figure it out this??

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In eclipse go to your interface .class file. 
On  press Ctrl+Shift+G. This will show you all occurrences of the interface and you can put breakpoints to all occurences.

Shortcut Ctrl+Shift+G work also with methods of inteface.

Comment: Mmm that is a good idea, i'm trying this. thank you! But i think this maybe a cumbersome solution when having a lot of occurences.

Answer (score 1):

If it's coming from your client side code, you can put a break point on the method signature in your `<SERVICE_NAME>Async.java` interface. Debugging should hit the break-point as long as you're running with the gwt codeserver.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer but already thought that,  but it is not possible to set a breakpoint on an interface method signature